# Javascript next video function

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm trying to create a form of video slideshow. I want to be able to have two buttons that go forward and backward through an array of video sources. Here is what I have so far.

```
<script>
 var vids = new Array();
vids[0] = "images/movie1.mp4"
vids[1] = "images/movie3.mp4"

var i = (vids[0]);
</script>

<script>
function next()
    {
        document.getElementById("myvideo").src=([i]);
        }
</script>

<video id="myvideo" width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="images/movie1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<button type="button" onclick="next()">try</button>
```

It seems simple enough, but when I try use functions that increment i by one (i++) it does not select the next video.

Essentially I need someone to help me create a method that makes the variable i move down to the next video of the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var vids = new Array();
vids[0] = "http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4";
vids[1] = "http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/trailer.mp4";
var i = 1;
function next()  {
        if (i > 1){
            window.alert("Too far");
            return;
        }
        document.getElementById("myvideo").src=vids[i];
        i++;
};
```

[a link](http://jsfiddle.net/vMQbY/1/) - your redesigned code. I didn't get what ([i]) meant.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be:

```
var vids = [
  "images/movie1.mp4",
  "images/movie3.mp4"
];

var i = 0;

function next() {

  if (i >= vids.length) {
    alert('too far!');
    return;
  }

  document.getElementById("myvideo").src=vids[i];
  i++;
};
```